# GeoNode commands: preceded by "geonode" or "python manage.py"?

Tags: geonode

It´s not really a problem but I would like to know the difference. I´m not a programmer. When I started with GeoNode 2.4 I used to run the commands as  `geonode name-of-the-command`
Migrating to 2.6, some of the commands didn´t work that way and now I´m using them as

```
python manage.py name-of-the-command
```

If I run `geonode updatelayers`, I get errors; but if I run `python manage.py updatelayers`, everything goes smooth.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If the geonode wasn't installed via quick installer, then you have to use "python manage.py"

Answer (score -1):

What does GeoNode doing? [link website Geonode](http://geonode.org) is seems to me like a US open layer dataset. Your are looking for open data for the US? You can use WMS/WFS data and import it in QGIS. If you want to use GeoNode 2.4 which OS are you using?

My experience is to do a full deinstallation (official way) and fresh install of the new software.

Comment: I know what GeoNode is, i´ve been using it for a while. The question is about GeoNode commands used in the server, as administrator.